# Was Parallel ForEach Possible before Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing

We all know streams allow us parallel foreach execution, e.g. (actual code not important):

```
Arrays.stream(ints).parallel()...
```

C# has something similar in the form of:

```
ints.AsParallel().Select(int=> ....
```

But! It also has the following syntax, which may or may not be older than the above:

```
Parallel.ForEach(ints, anInt => {});
```

Which brings me to my question - did Java have a way to do a parallel foreach relatively simply before Java 8? Googling this seems to produce no results, I also tried a couple of articles [here](https://jaxenter.com/java-performance-tutorial-how-fast-are-the-java-8-streams-118830.html), [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html), on Baeldung, etc, and see no older way to do this.

Is there one?

Comment: before java 8 there is no parallel processing, unless you define custom logic

Comment: *did Java have a way to do a parallel foreach* **Yes!** *relatively simply before Java 8* **No!**

Comment: @Deadpool I am definitely asking strictly about BUILT-IN parallel processing logic.

Comment: @Jai [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), etc are Java **7**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Oh, I always thought `ForkJoinPool` was introduced together with `Stream` API. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do parallel processing starting from Java7, i.e. before Java8 using Fork/Join framework. But you have to split the data source by your own, and wrap the code in a `ForkJoinTask` subclass, typically using one of its more specialized types, either `RecursiveTask` (which can return a result) or `RecursiveAction`. In your case since it has no return value you have to wrap your code in a `RecursiveAction` and submit all the sub-tasks into the common Fork/Join pool.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly, but Java 7 added the [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), which was specifically meant to execute decomposed subtasks (parts of a larger task) in parallel. This could easily be applied to a `Collection`.

Java 5 also added the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), which isn't specifically for running decomposed subtasks, but it could still be used for it with a little more work.

Comment: ... and for pre-Java 5 there is [backport jsr166](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/) (or you could implement it yourself)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look how things are done under the hood using a `Spliterator` (very simplified) : it just chunks the data into smaller pieces if size of the source is known (or creates a buffer if for example your source is an `Iterator` and you don't know it's size), you could theoretically do in with a simple `ThreadPool` and pass each chunk to an thread and than compute the result by merging those resulting.

Admittedly, that would be rather complicated, especially since `ForkJoinPool` uses the so called *work stealing* algorithm - and this would not be easy to implement with a pool, I guess. But `ForkJoinPool` was introduced in java-7, even if in java-8 it has some small adjustments if I remember correctly. So yes, this could have been done prior to java-8, but that would not be easy, by far.

Comment: Don’t overestimate the effect of work-stealing. In the end, you can do a “parallel for each” with Java 1.0 features, a comparison of the efficiency of the approaches is outside the scope of this question.